# awk does not print $2 from a file?

Tags: linux, awk

I am running this shell script

```
 #!/bin/sh
 for line in `cat file.txt`
 do
 Am=`echo $line| awk '{print $1}'`
 Bm=`echo $line| awk '{print $2}'`
 #my command Am +Bm.......
 done
```

I get this for first line:

```
  + cat file.txt
  + echo A
  + awk {print $1}
  + AM=A
  + echo A
  + awk {print $2}
  + Bm=
```

as you can see it does not pick up the value for Bm

```
     $ cat file.txt
     A 19
     B 81
     C 76
     D 31

   $ awk '{print $2}' file.txt
    19
    81
    76
    31

  $ awk '{print $1}' file.txt
    A
    B
    C
    D
```

Comment: If you're trying to run a command with successive pairs of arguments taken from a file, you may find `xargs` a better approach than `awk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to set your `IFS` to a newline:

```
set -f; # suppress wildcard expansion since `cat...` is unquoted
IFS=$'\n'; for line in `cat file.txt`; do
   Am=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
   Bm=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'`
   #my command Am +Bm.......
done
```

Though there are other methods also:

```
while read Am Bm junk; do
   #my command Am +Bm....
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Having two calls of awk in the script for every line in the text file is gross inefficiency on the part of the OP. So even though IFS will do the job, it would be better if the OP told us more about what he wants to do. The while loop is *much* better, btw.

Comment: Thanks but I use the first part of your code but still it does not solve the problem.

Comment: It is now printing the whole column instead of one line

Answer (score 1):

`for line in $(cat file.txt)` will iterate over every single glob in the file, one by one.  The input sent to `awk` will only ever have only one column of input, so `$2` will always be null.

Comment: SO what I shall I do to iterate by line?

Comment: Do it all in awk perhaps? Awk iterates line by line. It depends on what you want to do with Am and Bm afterwards, so you have to show that part of the script.

Comment: can you propose something?

Comment: I need to iterate line by line to get Am and Bm from each line to be used in my command.

Comment: Show the command! With its arguments! Don't make us guess. Update the question and add this information.

Answer (score 1):

`IFS` splits on by default the space character so your `for` loop actually loops over each "word"

```
$ for x in `echo a 19 b whatever`; do echo $x; done
a
19
b
whatever
$
```

A better approach might be to eliminate both the `for` loop and useless use of `cat` via something like

```
$ cat input
A 19
B 81
C 76
D 31
$ awk '{system("echo "$2" "$1)}' input
19 A
81 B
76 C
31 D
$
```

where `echo` would instead be your "my command"...